# Drag and drop div using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I got a Main Div where i can drop any text and this will be displayed as in a form shown in the below script.

I need to drag and drop the dynamically generated div to move it up or down ,from within the current div. Is this possible?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

  $(init);

  function init() {




  function addColumn(column) 
  {
    var iHtml;


    //Labeling and Tool Tip the Checkbox


   iHtml = "<div id='<%" + column + ".ClientID%>'><span title='ToolTipText'>"+
   "<input id='<%" + column + ".ClientID%>' type='checkbox' name='<%" + column + ".ClientID %>' />"+
    "<label for='<%" + column + ".ClientID%>'>MyCheckBox</label></span></div>";

    return iHtml
  }
```

}

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Draggable

Comment: Your code has some problems like mismatched braces `{}`. Please correct and if possible give us a jsfiddle link (http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Thanks for that document . How can i refer my dynamically generated div ? Is it possible to use wildcards in script?

Answer (score 3):

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/

Comment: can you tell me how i can refer the id of the name to the draggable method?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [jQuery ui](http://jqueryui.com/demos/). There are [draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/)/[dropable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/) and [sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/) plugins